# Enum Data Contract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a dataContract.

```
ItemInfo SearchItemByGuid(ClientEnum client, string itemGuid);
```

where ClientEnum is:

```
enum ClientEnum
{
Client1,
Client2,
}
```

I am going to expose the data contract though webHttpBinding. 
So I have to use WebGet.
some sort of...

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "items/{client}/{itemguid}"]
ItemInfo SearchItemByGuid(ClientEnum client, string itemGuid);
```

so the question is, how I can handle enum type in good manner....?

Ideas:

1. Make one more interface but with string instead of enum...
2. Implement IParameterInspector(parse string into enum)
3. QueryStringConverter?

any ideas?

**Update:**

It seems I found a solution:
so...

```
 public class ClientEnumQueryStringConverter : QueryStringConverter 
{
    public override object ConvertStringToValue(string parameter, Type parameterType)
    {
//here goes actual conversion
        return base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, parameterType);
    }

    public override string ConvertValueToString(object parameter, Type parameterType)
    {
//here goes actual conversion
        return base.ConvertValueToString(parameter, parameterType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(ClientEnum))
            return true;           

        return base.CanConvert(type);
    }
}
```

and finally....

```
 public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior    
{
    WebMessageFormat defaultOutgoingResponseFormat;
    public MyWebHttpBehavior()
    {
        this.defaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
        HelpEnabled = true;
    }

    public override WebMessageFormat DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return this.defaultOutgoingResponseFormat;
        }
        set
        {
            this.defaultOutgoingResponseFormat = value;
        }
    }

    protected override QueryStringConverter GetQueryStringConverter(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        return new ClientEnumQueryStringConverter ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Can't you just use an `int`? The framework should cast it to the relevant `enum` value.

Comment: I have well known problem.... Operation 'SearchItemByGuid' in contract 'blabla' has a path variable named 'client' which does not have type 'string'. Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'. I can make it work.. i hope using the UriTemplate = "items?client={client}&itemGuid={itemguid}" but this is why I have asked...in good manner.. :)

Comment: I can go with int... but I would like to keep an enum, because I would like to share the code base with c# apps and there Enums look much better.